# HADOOP_HOME and hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Hi I am trying to run hadoop on a server that has hadoop installed but I have no idea the directory where hadoop resides.  The server was configure by the server admin.

In order to load hadoop I use the use command from the dotkit package.

There may be several solutions but wanted to know where the hadoop package was installed, how to set up the $HADOOP_HOME variable, and how to approp run a hadoop streaming job, such as $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/mapred/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar, aka, `http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopStreaming`.

Thanks!  any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using a cloudera distribution then it's most probably in `/usr/lib/hadoop`, otherwise it could be anywhere (at the discretion of your system admin).

There are some tricks you can use to try and locate it:

1. `locate hadoop-env.sh` (assuming that locate has been installed and updatedb has been run recently)
2. If the machine you're running this on is running a hadoop service (such as data node, job tracker, task tracker, name node), then you can perform a process list and grep for the hadoop command: `ps axww | grep hadoop`
3. Failing the above two, look for the hadoop root directory in some common locations such as: `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local`, `/opt`
4. Failing all this, and assuming your current user has the permissions: `find / -name hadoop-env.sh`

Answer (score 0):

If you're install with rpm then it's most probably in `/etc/hadoop`.

Answer (score -4):

Why don't you try:

`echo $HADOOP_HOME`

Obiviously the above env variable has to be set before you could even issue hadoop executables from anywhere on the box.